# How to detect if any letters from second to last character of a word is capitalized in python? word length is unknown

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried this code but it didn't work:

```
word = input("Enter a word to be tested: ")

for character in word:
        if character[0] == character.lower() and character[1:] != character.lower:
            result = False
            print(result)
```

Comment: When you iterate over a string like that `character == character[0] and character[1:] == ''` by definition. Also you don't actually *call* the string method on both occasions you reference it. But could you expand on *"didn't work"* with a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is great, we'll just keep it.

```
word = input("Enter a word to be tested: ")
```

Now, we don't care about the first character, so let's see if the others are in lowercase, using [str.islower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower).

```
result = word[1:].islower()
assert result, 'Your string wasn\'t in lowercase from the second char onwards'
```